# Assigning default value during destructuring in v-slot

Tags: vuejs2, destructuring

The project set up by vue-cli and the options are babel, router, vuex and eslint/prettier.
I was following vue official guide to use destructuring and assigning default value as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props).

```
<current-user v-slot="{ user = { firstName: 'Guest' } }">
    {{ user.lastName }}
</current-user>
```

But with parsing error says

> Shorthand property assignments are valid only in destructuring patterns.